# Add value to an existing array.

Tags: php, html, arrays

How can I add this to an existing array?

```
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="contry" />
    <input type='number' name="num[]" value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='number' name="num[]" value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='number' name="num[]" value='0' class='qty' />
```

Array is:

```
$data = array("name" => $_POST['name], "contry" => $_POST['contry']);
```

At the end I has to be "par1" => "value of num[0]", "par2" => "value of num[1]".

I want to add the num[] to the end of the $data array.

Comment: I tryed array_push but no luck. I dont know how to use array push.

Comment: well, simply `$data['par1'] = $_POST['num'][0]` should work, isn't it?

Comment: if you're adding it to the end of the array, it's array_push(nameofyourarray, thingyouwanttoadd) so an associative array would be like array_push($data, 'contry'=> $_POST['contry']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add key/values with $array['keyname'] = 'something'.

So you can use

```
<form action="" method="post" > 
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="contry" />
    <input type='number' name="num[]" value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='number' name="num[]" value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='number' name="num[]" value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<?php

$data = array("name" => $_POST['name'], "contry" => $_POST['contry']);

foreach ($_POST['num'] as $k => $v) {
    $data['par'.($k+1)] = $v;
}
var_dump($data);
```

which will produce after filling the form with (Me, Meme, 1, 2, 4)

```
array (size=5)
  'name' => string 'Me' (length=2)
  'contry' => string 'Meme' (length=4)
  'par1' => string '1' (length=1)
  'par2' => string '2' (length=1)
  'par3' => string '4' (length=1)
```

If you have only 3 num's, you don't need to be that generic, and the code will be more readable if you do

```
$data['par1'] = $_POST['num'][0];
$data['par2'] = $_POST['num'][1];
$data['par3'] = $_POST['num'][2];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`array_push()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

something like this:

```
$num=$_POST['num'];
foreach($num as $val)
{
array_push($data, $val)
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: How can I add keys to those values?

num1 => 0

Comment: array_push($data, 'contry'=> $_POST['contry']);

Answer (score 0):

The `num` entries in your HTML will become their own array in PHP, so if you run `var_dump($_POST['num'])`, you'll get something like the following:

```
array(3)
  [0] => 5;
  [1] => 6;
  [2] => 7;
```

Therefore you can access it with the following statements:

```
echo($_POST['num'][0]); // Would echo 5, assuming the same values as above
echo($_POST['num'][2]); // Echos 7.
```

You can therefore just add `$_POST['num']` as a subarray of `$data`, or process it how you see fit, for example:

```
$data = array("name" => $_POST['name'], "contry" => $_POST['contry'], "num"=>$_POST['num']);
```

Then access using:

```
$data['num'][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you aren't having any trouble with getting the data from $_POST['name'] and $_POST['country'] then why not just use the same method to get the data from the numbers?

If the amount of numbers is dynamic (it looks like it might be) you can maybe change the code from being 'num[]' to being 'num0' and 'num1' etc. Then simply loop until you have gotten all their data.

Something like:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="country" />
<input type='number' name="num0" value='0' class='qty' />
<input type='number' name="num1" value='0' class='qty' />
<input type='number' name="num2" value='0' class='qty' />
```

and then:

```
$data = array("name" => $_POST['name'], "contry" => $_POST['country']);
$i = 0;
while($i >=0)
{
    if(isset($_POST['num' . $i])
    {
        $data['par' . $i] = $_POST['num' . $i];//this will add the part you want
        $i++;
    }
    else
    {
        $i = -1;
    }
}
```

This is only a simply example, and not the most elegant. It won't account for skipping numbers in the middle, but you see where I am going with the idea I hope.